# Why is 'True == not False' a SyntaxError?

Tags: python, boolean, comparison-operators

Comparing boolean values with `==` works in Python. But when I apply the boolean `not` operator, the result is a syntax error:

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Sep 16 2010, 18:02:00) 
[GCC 4.5.1 20100907 (Red Hat 4.5.1-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> True == True
True
>>> False == False
True
>>> True is not False
True
>>> True == not False
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    True == not False
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Why is this a syntax error? I would expect `not False` to be an expression that returns a boolean value, and `True == <x>` to be valid syntax wherever `<x>` is an expression with valid syntax.

Comment: Note, that "True is not False" is *not* the same as "True is (not False)".  "is not" is a distinct operator, which means "is not identical to", whereas "True is (not False)" reads as "True is identical to the boolean negation of False".  Just a remark, because your example seems, as if you would assume, that both of these are the same.

Comment: `True == not` is the actual syntax error, anything after that is irrelevant.

Comment: And for the record, this fails for **any** comparison operator plus `not`, **regardless of the types compared**. `True < not False`, `3 <= not 2`, `'Foo' > not 'False'`, `3.3 >= not 4.5`, `{} is not not []`, `set() == not None` and `slice() != not lambda: x` **all** raise the same syntax error. This is not limited to `== not` and booleans.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It has to do with [operator precedence in Python](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) (the interpreter thinks you're comparing True to not, since `==` has a higher precedence than `not`). You need some parentheses to clarify the order of operations:

```
True == (not False)
```

In general, you can't use `not` on the right side of a comparison without parentheses. However, I can't think of a situation in which you'd ever need to use a `not` on the right side of a comparison.

Comment: Is there a reason for the operator precedence, or is it just a dumb "feature"?

Comment: Wow; this is interesting. I can't think of any other language I know where negation has such low precedence, certainly not lower than equality!

Comment: @Jim: Historically and especially coming from math, most programming languages' operator precedence is mostly arbitrary. At least beyond addition and multiplication.

Comment: @Jim operator precedence is necessary for a language to understand the order in which operations occur. The arithmetic ones are math-based (dunno if you've heard of PEMDAS), but it gets a bit hairy with boolean/comparison operators. Different languages have different interpretations, but in Python this is the way it is. It's typically not a problem if you use parentheses liberally. I don't know of any particular reason for Python.

Comment: *Logical* inversion has low precedence in Python. In contrast, arithmetic negation (unary `-`) and bitwise inversion (`~`) both have quite high precedence.

Comment: And of course, as almost everything in Python, it makes perfect sense, as `== not` both looks weird, and can in most cases be replaced with `!=` anyway.

Comment: @RafeKettler : for using not on the right: Sometimes, naming simplicity. While not done, is better than, while undone == True.

Comment: @JimClay The reason is likely consistency with other comparison operators, where this precedence makes perfect sense imo: in `if not (foo.x * 2) + 1 < bar` you wouldn't expect `not (foo.x*2) + 1` to mean "1 exactly if  (foo.x*2) + 1 == 0 else 0", and then compare it to bar with "less than". Negating statements involving "<" is also more readable than negating "<" itself to ">=" in some cases.

Comment: The need to use `not` with parentheses to override precedence is explained in Note 3 of [Boolean Operations — `and`, `or`, `not`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) section of the current documentation.

Answer (score 13):

Answers claiming that the reason for `True == not False` constituting a syntax error had to do with operator precedence are mistaken. If that were the case, the expression `2 ** - 1` would yield a syntax error as well, which of course it doesn't. Precedence never causes an operator to be drawn in in place of an operand.

The true reason for `True == not False` being a syntax error is that there exists no syntax rule that would produce a [comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-comparison) therefrom, since

> comparison    ::=  or_expr (comp_operator or_expr)*

- i. e. after the comp_operator `==` an [or_expr](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-or-expr) must follow, which includes an xor_expr, an and_expr, a [shift_expr](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-shift-expr), an a_expr, an [m_expr](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-m-expr), an [u_expr](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-u-expr), a [power](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-power)…, but no [not_test](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-not-test).

By comparison, the precedence-wise similar construct `2 ** - 1` in accordance with the power rule

> power ::=  (await_expr | primary) ["**" u_expr]

has u_expr following the power operator `**`, thus allowing `- x` on the right hand side.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning where `not` *does* fit in here: an `inversion` is either `'not'` followed by another `inversion`, or a `comparison`. An `inversion` is the building block of a `conjunction`, which is the building block of a `disjunction`, which you can basically think of as one of the three basic types of `expression`s (the other two being conditional expressions and lambda expressions).

Comment: This argument is spurious. Of course precedence can explain both the behaviour of `True == not False` and `2 ** -1` because *`not` and unary negation have totally different precedence!* The fact that `or_expr` doesn't include `not_test` is *how the precedence is implemented!*

Comment: The argument "_`not` and unary negation have totally different precedence_" is irrelevant; relevant is the precedence difference between `==` and `not` compared to `**` and `-`. The insistence on mixing precedence with parsing leads the Python documentation to contradict itself by first placing `**` above `-` in the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) table and then noting _[\[5\]](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#id15) The power operator `**` binds less tightly than an arithmetic or bitwise unary operator …_.

Comment: In the operator precedence table, `==` is exactly one row above `not` and `**` is exactly one row above unary `-`. How can one still believe that precedence alone can explain that `True == not False` is a syntax error while `2**-1` isn't?

Comment: `**` and unary `-` don't actually follow a clean precedence hierarchy. They're stuffed in the precedence table like that because it'd be more awkward to do otherwise, but saying that one has higher precedence than the other isn't an accurate way to describe how the grammar for those operators works (hence the footnote). Breaking the precedence hierarchy was worth it for `**` because `x**-1` is a common operation, and because `**` is non-commutative, so people are less surprised when `x**-1` and `-x**2` are parsed differently... but people still get surprised by `-2**x` being `-(2**x)`.

Answer (score -3):

Python has an operator precedence (This is like Bodmas in maths. Certain operators are considered before others. Eg: multiplication operator is considered before addition). In python '==' comes before 'not' in the operator precedence. Therefore, in your line of code, the first thing that Python analyses is 'False == not'. Because this is incorrect syntax, an error is raised.

Comment: This adds absolutely nothing over the existing answers that have been around for over a decade

Answer (score -5):

I think what you are looking for is "and not".  This gives you the results you are looking towards.  If your comparing booleans what you have is a compound boolean expression, here is an example website [Compound Boolean Expression](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/ifstatements.html#compound-boolean-expressions).

```
>>> True and True
True
>>> True and not True
False
>>> True and not False
True
>>> False and not True
False
>>> False and not False
False
>>> False and False
False
```