# Strange SyntaxError in Python?

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
x = True
y = not not x
print(f"{y == not not x}") ## SyntaxError
```

Normally you would expect the script to just print `True`, but instead it throws a `SyntaxError`. Why does this happen?

(Using the identity check `is` instead of `==` also results in a `SyntaxError`.)

Comment: If I use the interactive mode of python and leave out the f-string this still happens.

Comment: And if you switch both sides, things suddenly work as expected: `not not x == y` returns `True`.

Comment: just add parentheses: `y == (not not x)`

Comment: @TimRoberts not a fstring issue, the expression itself is a syntax error.

Comment: `not` has lower precedence than `==`, so a `not` expression isn't valid as an `==` operand. Changing the grammar to make it work anyway has enough weird consequences that it's not worthwhile to do - for example, it would make `x == not y` mean something completely different from `not y == x`.

Comment: "And if you switch both sides, things suddenly work as expected" - no, `not not x == y` means `not not (x == y)`, not `(not not x) == y`.

Comment: I don't buy the precedence argument. I think the grammar rule mentioned in an answer in the duplicate question explains the issue better. Precedence change meanings of expressions but should not make an otherwise valid expression invalid.

Comment: @WeijunZhou: Quoting one of the comments on that answer, "The fact that `or_expr` doesn't include `not_test` is *how the precedence is implemented!*"

Comment: @user2357112 take a look at this non-accepted but more recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68400827/5014455

Comment: @user2357112 I have seen that argument already and I don't agree with it either.

Comment: @Julien: If `x` is 1 and `y` is 2, and you allowed `x == not y`, then `x == not y` would evaluate as `1 == (not 2)`, which is `False`, but `not y == x` would evaluate as `not (1 == 2)`, which is `True`.

Comment: @user2357112 yeah as soon as I wrote my comment I started thinking along those lines, but struggled to find the actual example thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided will produce a syntax error because the expression

> y == not not x

is not valid in Python. You cannot use multiple consecutive not operators in this way within an equality comparison.

If you want to compare the values of y and x using the equality operator, you should write it like this:

```
x = True
y = not not x
print(y == x)
```

With this code, it will print True to the console because y is assigned the value of True, and x is also True, so the comparison

> y == x

evaluates to True.

Comment: If I just use a single `not` operator instead of two this still happens.